# Using a Swoole \Swoole\Coroutine\Http\Client based HttpClientAdapter for Guzzle - How?

Tags: php, guzzle6

I have tried to implement a [Guzzle HandlerStack](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html) HttpClientAdapter for [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/) and use it via:

```
$handler = new \App\Swoole\HttpClientAdapter();
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
   'handler' => \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($handler),
]);
$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/foo');
```

The handler class looks like this:

```
namespace App\Swoole;

class HttpClientAdapter
{

    public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, array $options)
    {
        // [..] init and request modification, path/port extraction removed

        $cli = new \Swoole\Coroutine\Http\Client($ip, $port, $ssl);
        $cli->execute($path);
        $cli->close();

        return new Promise\FulfilledPromise(

            new Psr7\Response($cli->statusCode, $cli->headers, $cli->body)
        );
    }
}
```

This actually works - but only if i put in a [MockServer Proxy](http://www.mock-server.com/) in between.
Without, i just do not get any data back ... i have tried using different endpoints, but to no avail. Does anybody know how to tackle/debug the problem and/or is there a Swoole Guzzle Adapter out there in the wild?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this work is awesome.
But I suggest another httpclient based on swoole coroutine:https://github.com/swlib/saber/blob/master/README-EN.md

It's developed by swoole core developer and you will find it quite look like Guzzle.

Comment: Thanks, nice Library - The reason for me to go the guzzle route is that i need to use the AWS SDK which relies on Guzzle - Do you know of any way to use Sabre with the AWS SDK?